# UPDATE: Hide named ranges (columns) with dropdown in same sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu, named-ranges

I am attempting to create a script for a dropdown selection in cell B2, that when selected for one, will hide columns corresponding two the other choices in the list sheet.

The dropdown in cell B2 is has as its data validation criteria the following list:
**"NORMAL," "HARD," "MAX POINTS"**

And the following column ranges in the sheet correspond to the selections in parentheses:
Columns D-K ("NORMAL"), Columns L-S ("HARD"), Columns T-AA ("MAX POINTS")

I would like the script to work such that selection of one of the dropdown choices will hide the column ranges that correspond to the two other dropdown choices (i.e., if you select "HARD" it will hide Columns D-K as well as T-AA).

What am I doing wrong here? I'm sure quite a bit of course.
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OVOxTrCto1JH02Efw9iLcUihy7LPjK1WJLgNTYU3yGY/edit?usp=sharing)

**MODIFIED SCRIPT:** I got this to work properly for each when run separately, but it requires me to to unhide after each time, otherwise it compounds what is hidden. I have it set to trigger on edit.  It's so close, is there something about the trigger or perhaps I need to somehow add something that resets it to unhide all before I can change the selection? (not sure how though)

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var value1 = "NORMAL";
var value2 = "HARD";
var value3 = "MAX POINTS";
var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var cell = activeSheet.getRange("B2").getValue();

function HideColumn() {
  if(cell == value1) {
      activeSheet.hideColumns(12, (27-7+1));
  }
  else if(cell == value2) {
        activeSheet.hideColumns(4, (14-7+1));
        activeSheet.hideColumns(21, (14-7+1));
  }
   else if(cell == value3) {
      activeSheet.hideColumns(4, (22-7+1));
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no method hideRange in class Sheet

Comment: There is no method hideRange in class Range either

Comment: You cannot just make up methods of your own and expect them to be carried out.

Comment: Yes, I figured. I admit I don't know much at all with respect to scripts and tried to cobble it together. I didn't expect it to work. How can I make it functional, if you don't mind?

Comment: Try learning Javascript first and then return to Google Apps Script and read the documentation until you understand at least some of it.

Comment: BTW I don't think you can hide ranges.  You can hide rows and columns but not subsets of either.

Comment: Pretty rude response. I'm trying my best at something wholly new to me and asking for help for one thing. If you don't want to help I completely understand. I could have posed the question from scratch and maybe you wouldn't be offended by my mistakes that I'm sure are quite bad. But I tried.

Comment: You might be able to make the background equal the foreground and thus hide the data.

Comment: The named ranges should just be the entire columns I specified in my question, not any subsets of them. At least if I did that right. So functionally it should be hiding columns, but I guess I thought this might make it easier? Apparently it's the opposite though.

Comment: Then I'd recommend using hideColumns() as that is a method of class Sheet

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the follow up. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Hi and welcome. _What am I doing wrong here?_ From the perspective of creating an efficient data set, I respectfully suggest that it is a mistake to have three sets of columns (Columns D-K ("NORMAL"), Columns L-S ("HARD"), Columns T-AA ("MAX POINTS")) that are conditional on the dropdown. (You don't say whether the data fields are different in each case, but each set has 8 columns.) Why a mistake? Because you're creating duplicate (actually triplicate) data fields; it's inefficient and will complicate reporting. Lastly ;), it is the cause of this "problem".

Comment: Thank for the response.  In this case I do need to have three separate sets of data related to the variable and resultant conditions created. The 3 sets are different in each case here.  But perhaps I’ll just need to just forget about the drop-down component altogether if it’s screwing everything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a dropdown in Cell B2.

- There are three options: "Normal", "Hard", and "Max Points".
- Depending on the value selected, you want to show the columns for the selected value and hide the columns for the other options.

The script uses the `switch` statement [Doc ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/conditionals#switch_statements) as an alternative to an `IF` statement.

To run this answer:

- copy to the Project editor,
- create an installable `onEdit()` trigger. (enables the script to run when the dropdown cell is edited; and enables Event objects to be used)

---

```
// running as an installable onEdit() trigger
// watching cell B2
function showHideColumns(e){
  
  var sheetName = "Today's Matchups"
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG

  if (e.range.columnStart ==2 && e.range.rowStart ==2 && e.range.getSheet().getName() == sheetName){
    // correct sheet and correct cell
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: correct sheet and correct cell")
  }
  else{
    // not the correct sheet/cell
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: not the correct sheet/cell")
    return
  }
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  var value1 = "NORMAL";
  var value2 = "HARD";
  var value3 = "MAX POINTS";
  var value1ColStart = 4
  var value2ColStart = 12
  var value3ColStart = 20
  var valueSetNumCols = 8
  // Columns D-K ("NORMAL"), 
  // Columns L-S ("HARD"), 
  // Columns T-AA ("MAX POINTS")
 
  var cell = e.value
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: dropdown value = "+cell)

  switch (cell) {
    case value1: 
    // NORMAL
    // show NORMAL, hide Hard & Max Points
    // show all columns (including NORMAL)
    sheet.showColumns(value1ColStart,24)
    // hide Hard
    sheet.hideColumns(value2ColStart, valueSetNumCols)
    // hide MaxPoints
    sheet. hideColumns(value3ColStart, valueSetNumCols)
    break

    case value2: 
      // HARD
      // show HARD, hide Normal & Max Points
      // show all Columns
      sheet.showColumns(value1ColStart,24)
      // hide Normal
      sheet.hideColumns(value1ColStart, valueSetNumCols)
      // hide MaxPoints
      sheet. hideColumns(value3ColStart, valueSetNumCols)
      break

    default:
      // Max Points
      // show Max Points, hide Normal & Hard
      // show all Columns
      sheet.showColumns(value1ColStart,24)
      // hide Normal
      sheet.hideColumns(value1ColStart, valueSetNumCols)
      // hide Hard
      sheet. hideColumns(value2ColStart, valueSetNumCols)
  }
}
```

---

**UPDATE: *ALSO* SHOW/HIDE COLUMNS ON SHEET="Battle Results Output"**

```
// runnings as an installable onEdit() trigger
// watching cell B2
// also hide columns on "Battle Results Output"
function showHideColumns(e){
  
  var sheetName = "Today's Matchups"
  
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG

  if (e.range.columnStart ==2 && e.range.rowStart ==2 && e.range.getSheet().getName() == sheetName){
    // right sheet and right cell
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: right sheet and right cell")
  }
  else{
    // not the right sheet/cell
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: not the right sheet/cell")
    return
  }
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  var value1 = "NORMAL";
  var value2 = "HARD";
  var value3 = "MAX POINTS";
  var value1ColStart = 4
  var value2ColStart = 12
  var value3ColStart = 20
  var valueSetNumCols = 8
  // Columns D-K ("NORMAL"), 
  // Columns L-S ("HARD"), 
  // Columns T-AA ("MAX POINTS")
  /*
  *  HIDE columns on Battle Results Output
  */
  var battleResultsName = "Battle Results Output"
  var battleSheet = ss.getSheetByName(battleResultsName)
  // Value 1 = show D&E, Hide F,G&H
  var value1BattleColStart = 4 // Column D
  var value1BattleSetNumCols = 2
  // Value 2 = show F&G, Hide D,E&H
  var value2BattleColStart = 6 // Column F & G
  var value2BattleSetNumCols = 2
  // Value 3 = show H, Hide D&F
  var value3BattleColStart = 8 // Column D
  var value3BattleSetNumCols = 1
  // number of columns for all results
  var valueBattleShowAllCols = value1BattleSetNumCols+value2BattleSetNumCols+value3BattleSetNumCols
  
 
  var cell = e.value
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: dropdown value = "+cell)

  switch (cell) {
    case value1: 
    // NORMAL
    // show NORMAL, hide Hard & Max Points
    // show Normal
    sheet.showColumns(value1ColStart,24)
    // hide Hard
    sheet.hideColumns(value2ColStart, valueSetNumCols)
    // hide MaxPoints
    sheet.hideColumns(value3ColStart, valueSetNumCols)
    /*
    *  HIDE columns from Battle Results
    */
    // show all including Normal
    battleSheet.showColumns(value1BattleColStart,valueBattleShowAllCols)
    // hide Hard
    battleSheet.hideColumns(value2BattleColStart,value2BattleSetNumCols)
    // hide MaxPoints
    battleSheet.hideColumns(value3BattleColStart,value3BattleSetNumCols)
    break

    case value2: 
      // HARD
      // show HARD, hide Normal & Max Points
      // show Normal
      sheet.showColumns(value1ColStart,24)
      // hide Normal
      sheet.hideColumns(value1ColStart, valueSetNumCols)
      // hide MaxPoints
      sheet.hideColumns(value3ColStart, valueSetNumCols)
      /*
      *  HIDE columns from Battle Results
      */
      // show all including Normal
      battleSheet.showColumns(value1BattleColStart,valueBattleShowAllCols)
      // hide Normal
      battleSheet.hideColumns(value1BattleColStart,value1BattleSetNumCols)
      // hide MaxPoints
      battleSheet.hideColumns(value3BattleColStart,value3BattleSetNumCols)
      break

    default:
      // Max Points
      // show Max Points, hide Normal & Hard
      // show Normal
      sheet.showColumns(value1ColStart,24)
      // hide Normal
      sheet.hideColumns(value1ColStart, valueSetNumCols)
      // hide Hard
      sheet. hideColumns(value2ColStart, valueSetNumCols)
      /*
      *  HIDE columns from Battle Results
      */
      // show all including Normal
      battleSheet.showColumns(value1BattleColStart,valueBattleShowAllCols)
      // hide Normal
      battleSheet.hideColumns(value1BattleColStart,value1BattleSetNumCols)
      // hide Hard
      battleSheet.hideColumns(value2BattleColStart,value2BattleSetNumCols)
  }
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Selection: "+cell+" the end")
}
```

---

Comment: Thanks so much again. If I wanted to hide columns in the same document, but a different worksheet based on the same dropdown selecttion, do you know how I could update the script to add that?

For 'Today's Matchups' dropdown selection:
1) NORMAL, I was hoping to hide 'Battle Results Output" columns F-H
2) HARD, I was hoping to hide 'Battle Results Output" columns D and G-H
3) MAX POINTS, I was hoping to hide 'Battle Results Output" columns D-F

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EbCPK1ufX3pElaUPJb36RA4XRXpRRGt8l9BkjsN_adM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Refer updated answer.